# Add url variables to href link through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following links on my page, but i want to add some url varaibles to them when the page loads through javascript.

## Links:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/home/">Home</a>
<a href="http://www.test.com/business/">Business</a>
<a href="http://www.test.com/commercial/">Commercial</a>
```

## Want to change them to:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/home?city=miami&tel=7777777777">Home</a>
<a href="http://www.test.com/business?city=miami&tel=7777777777">Business</a>
<a href="http://www.test.com/commercial?city=miami&tel=7777777777">Commercial</a>
```

I don't have an id on any of the href links so i can't figure out how to find them within the html. Can someone please help me with this.

Thank you

## UPDATE - SNIPPET FROM HTML

```
<div class="menu_wrapper">
<nav id="menu" class="menu-960px-grid-container"><ul id="menu-960px-grid" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-3064" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-67 current_page_item"><a href="http://www.test.com/Home/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-3042" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.test.com/business/"><span>Business</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-3043" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://www.test.com/commercial/"><span>Commercial</span></a></li>
</ul></nav><a class="responsive-menu-toggle " href="#"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a>                    
                </div>
```

Comment: Is it all links on the page? Is there a way to select the ones you need? AKA they live in a menu? It is a simple select links, each loop, addend the querystring

Comment: Did you try anything? Like `each`.

Comment: Where are you getting those values from?

Comment: The values come from another javascript that i have that gets the url values in the incoming page request and then stores them in a variable, "city" and "tel". now the main issue is that i have a bunch of links on the page but i only want to change those 3 and i can't figure out how to find them since they don't have any "ids" on them and i don't want to do a global change and change all links on the page since i only want those 3

Comment: You can select them based on their parent elements, but we can't show you exactly how to do that as you've not shown enough of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you could cycle each `a` tag in the page, then remove the last character of its `href`, and finally append `?city=miami&tel=7777777777`:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").each(function(i, v) {
        var href = $(v).attr("href");
        href = href.substr(0, href.length - 1) + "?city=miami&tel=7777777777";
        $(v).attr("href", href);
    });
})
```

**UPDATE**

Since you updated your HTML code, adding `id` attributes to your `a` tags' parents, you could apply the above rule to each of them, by simply changing only the jQuery selector:

```
$(function() {
    $("#menu-item-3064 a, #menu-item-3042 a, #menu-item-3043 a").each(function(i, v) {
        var href = $(v).attr("href");
        href = href.substr(0, href.length - 1) + "?city=miami&tel=7777777777";
        $(v).attr("href", href);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that, i would love to use this but i don't want to change all the links on the page, i only want a specific 3

Comment: So use a selector that gives you only those 3. `$('.menu a')`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through them with for.  Do the same to check.  The below does so without the jquery requirement.

```js
// This is your array of links to find and change
var linksToChange = ["http://asdf.com/home/", "http://asdf.com/busi/", "http://asdf.com/test/"]

// some external vars
var city = "miami",
  tel = "7777777";

// Generate your string to add
var stringToAdd = "?city=" + city + "&tel=" + tel;

// Get all "a" tags
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i<links.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < linksToChange.length; j++) {
    if (linksToChange[j] == links[i].href) {
      // Modify link here
      links[i].href = links[i].href.slice(0,-1) + stringToAdd;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="http://asdf.com/home/">1</a>
<a href="http://asdf.com/busi/">2</a>
<a href="http://asdf.com/other/">3</a>
<a href="http://asdf.com/more/">4</a>
<a href="http://asdf.com/test/">5</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr(fn)` to loop over them and use `$('#menu a')` as the selector

```
$('#menu a').attr('href', function(index, oldHref){
     return oldHref +'?city=miami&tel=7777777777'
});
```

Alternatively an `<a>` tag has a `search` property

```
$('#menu a').each(function(){
   this.search = 'city=miami&tel=7777777777';
});
```

A simple way to create your query string is to use [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

```
var data ={
    city:'miami',
    tel : '555-555-555'
}

var str = $.param(data); // "city=miami&tel=555-555-555"
```